# Scala functions lose variable type in list?

Tags: scala, generics, akka, type-erasure

**Background:**

I'm trying to reduce code and improve code reuse in Akka by dynamically creating/combining partial functions (case ...) from anonymous functions in Scala.

To create these partial functions I need access to the functions' parameter type though (using a type parameter T), but unfortunately this is subject to type erasure.

I found that using `TypeTag`s or `TypeClass`es I could deal with that, which is great. However, rather than converting my functions into partial functions one at a time, I'd like to do this in batch using `.map()`.

However, this appears to be failing; when using the function through a map, it seems T suddenly becomes `Nothing` instead, rendering my function dysfunctional (no pun intended).

**TL;DR**: can I get that lst(0) to give String as well?

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
def fn = (s: String) => {}
def check[T](fn: T => Unit)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]) = ct
check(fn)
//scala.reflect.ClassTag[String] = java.lang.String
val lst = List(fn).map(check)
lst(0)
//scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = Nothing
```

For the Akka-curious, my actual function in question, rather than the above `check()`:

```
def caseFn[T](fn: T => Unit)(implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Actor.Receive = {
  case ct(msg: T) => {
    fn(msg)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it working by changing

```
val lst = List(fn).map(check)
```

to

```
val lst = List(fn).map(check(_))
```

What is going on here?

In the `map(check)` case, Scala does so called `eta-expansion` to convert the method (`check`) to a function, see 6.26.5 of the [Scala Language Specification Version 2.9](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf):

> **6.26.5 Eta Expansion**
>
> Eta-expansion converts an expression of method type to an equivalent expression of function type.  It proceeds in two steps.  First, one identifies the maximal sub-expressions of *e*; let's say these are *e_1*,...,*e_m*.  For each of these, one creates a fresh name *x_i*.  Let *e'* be the expression resulting from replacing every maximal subexpression *e_i* in *e* by the corresponding fresh name *x_i*.  Second, one creates a fresh name *y_i* for every argument type *T_i* of the method (i=1,...n).  The result of eta-conversion is then:
>
> ```
> { val x_1 = e_1;
>   ...
>   val x_m = em;
>   (y_1: T_1,...,y_n:T_n) => e'(y_1,...,y_n)
> }
> ```

So in the `map(check)`, Scala performs *eta-expansion* and has to infer the type (generated during eta-expansion) of the generic method `check`.  Due to limitations of the type inference in Scala, it will infer `Nothing` instead of `String`, therefore the first version does not work, while the second does.

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this it works better:

```
val lst = List(fn).map(check(_))
// lst: List[scala.reflect.ClassTag[String]] = List(java.lang.String)
```

Not entirely sure why.

Comment: > Not entirely sure why.  => eta-expansion :), see my answer for more

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> check _
res19: (Nothing => Unit) => scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing] = <function1>

scala> check(_: String => Unit)
res20: (String => Unit) => scala.reflect.ClassTag[String] = <function1>

scala> List(fn).map(check)
res21: List[scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing]] = List(Nothing)

scala> List(fn).map(check _)
res22: List[scala.reflect.ClassTag[Nothing]] = List(Nothing)

scala> List(fn).map(check(_))
res23: List[scala.reflect.ClassTag[String]] = List(java.lang.String)
```